# How to read lottie animation in Xamarin forms C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin Forms. I would to read my lottie file named "LeafGameAnim.json" in c# but the animation not display

My xaml looks like this :

```
<forms:AnimationView
AnimationSource="EmbeddedResource"
x:Name="LeafGame_Anim"
 IsVisible="True"     
RepeatMode="Infinite"
AutoPlay="True"  />
```

My C# looks like this :

```
var jsonFileName = "Les.MyData.MyAnimation.LeafGameAnim.json";
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(jsonFileName);

using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
   LeafGame_Anim.SetAnimationFromJson(json);   
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Look at this example of how to specify the AnimationSource in the XAML:  https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/blob/develop/Samples/Forms/Example.Forms/Pages/EmbeddedPage.xaml

Comment: @Jason this work on Xaml I would like to read from .Net code .  I have updated my code

Comment: The method you had in the original post takes a json string, not a file name.  There are many existing posts about how to read the contents of an embedded resource

Comment: @Jason I am still looking. If any one have a solution I will take it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: it still not working

Comment: Please edit your question to show the current state of your code.  “Not working” is not a useful description of your problem

Comment: I have updated: by "not working" I am saying , the animation does not appear

Comment: You do not appear to be following any of my suggestions.  You are not using the `SetAnimationFromJson` method you had in your original post, and you are not loading the json file from Resources as shown in the linked post

Comment: @Jason I have update the code. The animation still not appear

Comment: Your resourceName is not correct.  If you debug the code it should be obvious that it is not reading the file

Comment: @Jason I have update the post with the structure of my code

Comment: Is that files build action set to EmbeddedResource?

Comment: @Jason Yes you were right it is working now